# Listing text overflows if size of the text is too long

Tags: html, css

[image: Image of overflow]

As seen from the second entry, if the text is too long then it overflows the list.

I have tried several ways to try to display correctly including overflow:hide, 
word-wrap and others. 
My issue is that only when I click on the second attribute is when these styles really have an effect as shown below:
[image]

However my class don't make use of .selected selector and so this seems bizzare.

Here are a few code snippets of my HTML and CSS:

```
                    <div class="list_header">
                        <div class="col-xs-4 list_content">        
                            <span><b>Attribute</b></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 list_content ">
                            <b>Value</b>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2 list_content ">
                            <b>Unit</b>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ul context-menu data-target="metadata_list_menu" ng-class="{ 'highlight': highlight, 'expanded' : expanded }" class="selectable general_list_item">
                        <li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee metadata_item" ng-class-odd="'light_back_option'" ng-class-even="'light_back_option_even'" ng-repeat="avu in available_metadata" on-last-repeat>
                            <span class="q_column size1 metadata_attribute">{{avu.avuAttribute}}</span><span class="q_column size2 metadata_value">{{avu.avuValue}}</span><span class="q_column size3 metadata_unit">{{avu.avuUnit}}</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

The CSS:

```
.q_column{
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
border-right:1px solid #C7C9C7;
}

.size1{
width:33%;
}

.size2{
width:50%;
word-wrap: break-word;
}

.size3{
width:17%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.size2 {
    width:50%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

That's it